# Links to Top and Bottom with CSS

Tags: html, css, anchor

Can somebody tell me what's a good way to create to links for jumping around the page?

I already have the one for to-go-top and works just fine but I'm having some troubles when creating the one for the to-go-bottom.

This is what I'm trying to do(obviously I have a different image for the bottom one):

[image]

```
<a href="#Top" name="Top" id="Top" class="cd-top cd-is-visible cd-fade-out" >Top</a>
<a href="#Bot" name="Bot" id="Bot" class="cd-bottom cd-is-visible cd-fade-out">Bottom</a>
```

and this is the CSS that I'm using:

```
/******************** Back to top and/or bottom ********************/
.cd-top {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 45%;
  right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  /* image replacement properties */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #03a400 url(images/cd-top-arrow.svg) no-repeat center 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}

.cd-top.cd-is-visible, .cd-top.cd-fade-out, .no-touch .cd-top:hover {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}
.cd-top.cd-is-visible {
  /* the button becomes visible */
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 63;
}
.cd-top.cd-fade-out {
  /* if the user keeps scrolling down, the button is out of focus and becomes less visible */
  /*    opacity: .5; */
}
.cd-top:hover {
  background-color: #489148;
  opacity: 1;
}

.cd-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 45%;
  right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  /* image replacement properties */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #03a400 url(images/cd-bottom-arrow.png) no-repeat center 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}
```

Here is the Javascript that I'm using:

```
;jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link is shown
    var offset = 300,
        //browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link opacity is reduced
        offset_opacity = 1200,
        //duration of the top scrolling animation (in ms)
        scroll_top_duration = 700,
        //grab the "back to top" link
        $back_to_top = $('.cd-top');

        //grab the "back to bottom" link
        $back_to_bottom = $('.cd-bottom');      

    //hide or show the "back to top" link
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $back_to_top.addClass('cd-is-visible') : $back_to_top.removeClass('cd-is-visible cd-fade-out');
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > offset_opacity ) {
            $back_to_top.addClass('cd-fade-out');
        }
    });

    //smooth scroll to top
    $back_to_top.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0 ,
            }, scroll_top_duration
        );
    });

    //hide or show the "back to bottom" link
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        ( $(this).scrollBottom() > offset ) ? $back_to_bottom.addClass('cd-is-visible') : $back_to_bottom.removeClass('cd-is-visible cd-fade-out');
        if( $(this).scrollBottom() > offset_opacity ) {
            $back_to_bottom.addClass('cd-fade-out');
        }
    });

    //smooth scroll to bottom
    $back_to_bottom.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0 ,
            }, scroll_top_duration
        );
    });

});
```

For some reason I cannot make the second button appear on the screen.If somebody can tell me a better approach or tell where's my error I would be mora than grateful

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is achievable only with JS

Comment: Yes, I know, check my updated version. thanks

Comment: You just need to make some small tweaks to your CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/twvn1z3s/2/

Comment: Yes, I already modified it but somehow when clicking in the bttom one it does not goes to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Clicking button isn't working because you've set scrollTop to 0. If you update it to the height of the page, it works. Here's an updated fiddle with a scrollable page: http://jsfiddle.net/twvn1z3s/7/

---

Assuming this is your entire CSS - You need to make small tweaks to your CSS. For instance, you define:

`.cd-top.cd-is-visible` where you set `opacity`/`visibility`, but not for the `bottom` button.

Modify the old rule to:

```
.cd-top.cd-is-visible,
.cd-bottom.cd-is-visible{
    /* the button becomes visible */
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And it will appear. Once the bottom button is visible, you'll need to tweak the positioning of the buttons so they don't overlap (as they both have their offsets set to values that cause a slight overlap) - I set top to 30% here: http://jsfiddle.net/twvn1z3s/2/

Comment: Yes, I fixed that now, thanks but I still need help with the JS when clicking on the arrow down it never goes to the bottom.

Comment: actually what it does when clicking on it is the same as the top one(goes to the top instead of to the bottom)

Comment: For the bottom click handler, it has `scrollTop: 0 ,` <- is that intentional?

Comment: @Kevin - Here's the fiddle updated, with scrollTop set to document.body.scrollHeight: http://jsfiddle.net/twvn1z3s/7/

Comment: hell yes, that's what I need it man, thanks!!. Do you want me to accept your current answer or do you want to create another one with the link to jsfiddle (that way future people will not have to look on the comments) and accept that one?

Comment: Awesome, sounds good Kevin! And this one works :) I've edited the answer to include Fiddles for both the JavaScript clicking and the CSS.